JSON Schema propertyNames doesnt seem to work
i am trying to use a schema to validate some input data in an ionic WebApp. But it doesnt seem to work the way i want it to. Schema and example input data here: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/ukPB5SkA.
specifically the object should be allowed to contain properties "header" "footer" "color" and "typeface". Yet other properties seem to be allowed despite additionalProperties being set to false.
I also tired adding:
    "patternProperties": {
        ".*": "string"
    }

i use ajv in my project so i tried using a format:
import addFormats from 'ajv-formats';
import Ajv2019 from "ajv/dist/2019"
const ajv = new Ajv2019({strict: true, removeAdditional: 'all',  allowUnionTypes: true, passContext: true})
addFormats(ajv)
ajv.addFormat("collection", {
  type: "string",
  validate: (x) => Object.keys(Properties).includes(x)
})

enum Properties {
  'header',
  'footer',
  'color',
  'typeface'
}

const complexSchemaFormat = {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "propertyNames": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "collection"
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
  }
} as const

    const complexInput2 = {
      "jiii": 2,
      "juuu": "laal"
    }

  protected doThing() {
    const complexIsValid3 = ajv.validate(complexSchemaFormat,complexInput2)
    console.log(complexIsValid3) // is true, should be false
    }


Alternative from the previous answer
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "header": {"type": "string"},
    "footer": {"type": "string"},
    "color": {"type": "string"},
    "typeface": {"type": "string"}
  }
}


propertyNames is an applicator similar to properties.
The description of this keyword states:

The propertyNames keyword in is used to define constraints on the property names within an object instance. It allows you to specify a schema that all the property names in an object instance must adhere to.

The way you have written your schema, the actual property name defined is propertyNames.
{
  "propertyNames": "something"
}


It should be something like this where you want to constraint the naming to your enum. BUT, this doesn't give you way to constraint the values of those properties.
{
"$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
"propertyNames": {
   "pattern": "header|footer|color|typeface"
  }
}


You probably really want to do something like this where you don't even need to define a custom format. JSON Schema validation will validate what you are trying to do with the custom format with the following
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "unevaluatedProperties": false,
  "patternProperties": {
    "header|footer|color|typeface": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}

This basically says, any property defined in this schema must be one of the values in patternProperties and then it must validate as a string

I think there's probably something to say about readability and performance of this.  If you're just explicitly listing properties, I think the properties keyword conveys the intent better.  And since patternProperties requires regex evaluation, its performance will be worse than just the string-matching of properties.

That's a good point. The original question was centered around an enum in typescript.  But you're right, just properties probably makes more sense if the enum is only a few properties

Thank you for your answers: In my usecase i have a number of classes that each take a distinct range of Properties for its functions. For some of the classes its quite a lot of properties. Therefore i am looking for a more reusable approach. Preferably one that lets me use already defined enums of properties and if possible one that doesnt use regex for performance reasons as mentioned by @gregsdennis

I found a suitable solution. I put the enums into separate schemas and then used these subschemas to

have only the propertyNames allowed that are keys of an ts enum
have an array property "flags" allowed that can only have the listed properties as members.
This makes the schema much longer and kind of convoluted but it does what i want it to do:

export const PropertiesSchema = {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$ref": "#/definitions/Properties",
  "definitions": {
    "Properties": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "flags": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Flags"
          }
        }
      },
        "propertyNames": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/StyleParams"
      },
    },
    "StyleParams": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "flags",
        ...Object.keys(properties) // ts enum
      ]
    },
    "Flags": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        classconstants.Constant1,
        classconstants.Constant2,
        classconstants.Constant3
      ]
    }
  }
} as const

